# why dependency jdk's library at compile APK?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, compiler-errors, java

all:
   I want to use jackson in my work.
   Import it like this by gradle:

```
compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.8.5') 
compile 'javax.xml.stream:stax-api:1.0-2'
```

so,I got an error like this:

```
 Error:trouble processing "javax/xml/stream/EventFilter.class":
 Error:Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
 Error:when not building a core library.
 Error:This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
 Error:in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
 Error:Eclipse).
```

I find this class is realized at rt.jar(part of open-jdk's jre), also I find android studio dependency it by default like this :
   [image]
   how to disable this jdk dependency ?

Comment: Hey, were you able to fix this by any chance? I am currently in the same boat and stuck